# how to call some logic in my views after rendering template in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using **form.py** and the user is typing some Email-id, let us say I want to send an email to that particular email and write all that email into google sheet using gspread, I am able to do this in my **views.py**, but the problem is it's taking a lot of time to write which slow down the rendering process.

Is there any other way I can use my logic after rendering the template.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some queuing mechanism like worker and consumer to avoid this problem.

For example `Celery`. 
Steps to do for sending email:
1. Add email and info to the queue referred as task
2. Consume the queue. (It runs in the different process may be parallel too)

You can also use `Channels` newly added in Django family of apps.
This will provide you an `asynchronous` way to handle email/any other `deferred task`.